# Is there some jQuery conflict here?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I'm customizing a wordpress theme called [Accordium](http://accordium.parkerandkent.com/accordium/), and I have decided to add infinite scroll to it using a wordpress plugin called [pbd-ajax-load-posts](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/). In the theme, when you click on a post in archive view, an accordian animation plays by standard. The problem is, the plugin fails to render the default accordion style of posts in the archive when you click on Load More Posts [farthest bottom, in Persian] and shows it like when a post is clicked, leaving it with a fixed open accordian.

> - screenshot #1: h.dropcanvas.com/bf49k/ajax_load.jpg
> - screenshot #2: h.dropcanvas.com/5aoza/ajax_load2.jpg

On my site, it seems that it only shows class="pk_entry", rather than the entire class="pk_post", but I might be mistaken. It seems to me that there should be a jQuery or PHP conflict, but you know I'm no professional. You can see my site at

> etrewp.ir/ezdevaj.ma

Answer (score 1):

If I click on the large button on the bottom of your page (the one in your first screenshot), then your page is called with the parameter `?paged=2`. If I call your page directly with this parameter, I got the following JS error `TypeError: $ is not a function`

From the source of your page:

```
<!-- Clickable Nav Script-->
    <script>
    $(function () { ... }
    </script>
```

Replace it with this:

```
<!-- Clickable Nav Script-->
    <script>
    jQuery(function ($) { ... }
    </script>
```

Comment: That actually corrected the navigation on the left beneath the logo, but not my original problem.  Anyway, thank you. (By the way, I have no background now under that navigation menu you just helped me with. You know there was one with the CSS fallback before. How can I do that?)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using custom jquery files, before installing check whether same functionality file exist with different name
2. Replace "$" with "jQuery" in custom script